# Updating a ListView With CursorAdapter When Querying Database

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView and an CustomListAdapter that extends CursorAdapter. I'm using a LoaderManager to load the data into my CustomListAdapter when I first load the Fragment containing the ListView. That all works fine. I'm using ContentProviders so any updates or changes to the underlying data in the database are reflected in the Listview.

Now I want to allow the user to search for specific items in the list. So in other words i want to update the list view based on the search query obtains from the SearchDialog. I've got the SearchDialog working and I'm up to the point where I receive the intent in ParentActivity of the ListViewFragment, with the search query. However I'm not really sure what I should be doing now.

I was thinking of detaching and then re-attaching the Fragment to the ParentActivity passing the search query string to the ListViewFragment so that the onCreateLoader() method of the fragment could use the query to do another search. This seemed like an easy way to achieve what I wanted to do.

Is this the correct way to update a ListView based on a search? Or is this overkill for what I'm trying to do? Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Kind Regards

Comment: `I was thinking of detaching and then re-attaching the Fragment to the ParentActivity passing the search query string to the ListViewFragment so that the onCreateLoader() method of the fragment could use the query to do another search. This seemed like an easy way to achieve what I wanted to do.` Maybe try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants to know, my requirement changed and instead of using the same Activity to view the results, I sent the results to a new SearchResultActivity that was re-using the ListViewFragment.

I created an instance variable on the ListViewFragement that would store the query string. When creating a new instance of the Fragment, it expects a value for this query string. When I load the Fragment from my first Activity, the string is null and the onCreateLoader() by default loads all the results. When I load the Fragment from SearchResultActivity I pass in the query result from the SearchDialog and the onCreateLoader() will use the query to return a Cursor based on a specific selection.

I didn't need to attach and re-attach the fragment in anyway. However if I was to use the same Activity and ListViewFragment to display the search results, instead of detaching and re-attaching the fragment to the activity, I would probably use the restartLoader method of LoaderManager:

[LoaderManager Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E))

Comment: might be a whole new question

Comment: I could probably put together an example of this if people are interested.